# AbstractController::DoubleRenderError with controller exception handling

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

In my Rails 3.1 app, I have a `rescue_from` on top of the base API controller that looks like this:

```
rescue_from Exceptions::InvalidApiKey, :with => :invalid_api_key
```

in the invalid_api_key looks like this:

```
def invalid_api_key
    Rails.logger.debug "Invalid API key"
    render :json => {:error => :invalid_api_key}, :status => :forbidden
end
```

There is a `before_filter` that checks the API key and throws an InvalidApiKey exception if needed.

However, I get an `AbstractController::DoubleRenderError` when I try the controller with the wrong API key, as it tries to render in the exception handler and also in the original action.

How can I avoid this?

Comment: `render(:json...) and return` ?

Comment: and return is going to return from invalid_api_key and not disturb the flow back into the main action.

Comment: ok, misread this was in a before_filter

Answer (score 1):

You need to `return false` in `before_filter` to stop the controller's chain.

Otherwise, it firstly renders error in `invalid_api_key` and goes to called action using "usual" flow (since you've rescued from exception) and tries to render again  from the action.

So

```
def invalid_api_key
    Rails.logger.debug "Invalid API key"
    render :json => {:error => :invalid_api_key}, :status => :forbidden 
    false
end
```

should solve the issue